# print jscrollpane having multiple pages

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jeditorpane, printers

I searched a lot, and tried so many examples from the internet, but I haven't found a suitable example. My problem is, I am having a `jscrollpane`, it contains `JEditorPane`, and the content of `JEditorPane` is dynamic, when I prints `jscrollpane`, it prints first page only, but it has 5 to 6 pages. So please help me how can I print all pages from `jscrollpane`. Please help me

Comment: By "print" do you mean printing to paper? If so, you *don't* print the JScrollPane but rather you print the JEditorPane. Or perhaps better -- use a Java library for printing out data such as JasperReports.

Comment: i also tried on jeditorpane, but its also printing only first page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hovercraft Full Of Eels comment. Here I found an [article](http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html) to Printing/Previewing of the `JEditorPane` content. May be use full.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.